# Oom-kill event during bowtie-build index on cancer cell line 100X illumina WGS

Tags: bowtie

I am trying to create a BOWTIE index from WGS data of a cancer cell line (100X coverage). I previously mapped my reads to the Hg38 genome, then converted the file to a FASTA file using samtools.

Then I ran bowtie-build here on the cluster using the following submission

```
command: sbatch -n 1 --mem-per-cpu=20000 -c 11 BOWTIE_build_Genome_index.sh
```

With the following .sh file:

```
module load BOWTIE && bowtie-build Reference_genome_gRNA_mapping/mapped_reads.fasta 8814_short_read_BOWTIE_index

But keep getting the following error despite changing the memory: 
Start - Wed Aug  2 17:05:14 BST 2023
[+] Loading BOWTIE 1.3.1
Settings:
  Output files: "8814_short_read_BOWTIE_index.*.ebwtl"
  Line rate: 7 (line is 128 bytes)
  Lines per side: 1 (side is 128 bytes)
  Offset rate: 5 (one in 32)
  FTable chars: 10
  Strings: unpacked
  Max bucket size: default
  Max bucket size, sqrt multiplier: default
  Max bucket size, len divisor: 4
  Difference-cover sample period: 1024
  Endianness: little
  Actual local endianness: little
  Sanity checking: disabled
  Assertions: disabled
  Random seed: 0
  Sizeofs: void*:8, int:4, long:8, size_t:8
Input files DNA, FASTA:
  Reference_genome_gRNA_mapping/8814_Hg38_short_read.fasta
Reading reference sizes
  Time reading reference sizes: 00:47:55
Calculating joined length
Writing header
Reserving space for joined string
Could not allocate space for a joined string of 343527239163 elements.
Switching to a packed string representation.
Reading reference sizes
  Time reading reference sizes: 00:46:53
Calculating joined length
Writing header
Reserving space for joined string
Joining reference sequences
/var/spool/slurmd/job4829180/slurm_script: line 5: 26958 Killed
ls: cannot open directory '/etc/munge': Permission denied
ls: cannot open directory '/etc/ssl/private': Permission denied
It took 6710 seconds
Finish - Wed Aug  2 18:57:04 BST 2023
slurmstepd-linux033: error: Detected 1 oom-kill event(s) in step 4829180.batch cgroup. Some of your processes may have been killed
```

I tried to increase the memory, but that didn't help